# AJAX multiple checkboxes / multiselect

Tags: javascript, ajax

Alrighty then, howdy first off; quick question I have a form that has multiple check boxes with the same name (i.e. -

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myname[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myname[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myname[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myname[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myname[]" value="4" />
```

)

I am not using JQuery as I don't need that much baggage it is a very simple script that does does what is says on the tin, just serialize a form for use in an ajax post request. I would like to know though how to serialize the multiple checkboxes above for correct use in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to grab all the checkboxes with `document.getElementsByName` and loop to get what's checked.

```
var checkedValues = [];
var allCheckboxes = document.getElementsByName("myname[]");
for(var i = 0; i < allCheckboxes.length; i++){
    if (allCheckboxes[i].checked)
       checkedValues.push(allCheckboxes[i].value);
}
```

I assume PHP can treat a comma-delimited list of values as an array:

```
checkedValues.join();   //tested and produces ---> 0,3,4
```

Comment: I apologize, this was actually the correct answer and I never marked it as such, thank you :)

Comment: Its work for other database dynamodb also